# How does Linux determine a device class?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Linux newbie question.

Just wondering how Linux determines which device class a device is? Specifically, when I plug a barcode scanner in how does it know it is an ttyACM device? I have a scanner that works with my Linux OS but the new model isn't recognized so I'm wondering if I can alter a file somewhere in the system that tells it to recognize the scanner as ttyACM0 and use the existing drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB devices (I assume your scanner is USB) are identified by *vendorId* and *productId* (two 16bit integers), each driver fill an array with the list of supported vendor/prods id (creating a relation vendor:prod->driver), I guess at compile time all the id in the array are merged together in a list which then is used for a lookup search when a device is plugged in.

Usually you can see vendor and product id of the attached device with `dmesg` command right after the device is plugged in (or with `lsusb`).

For `ttyACM` see `acm_ids[]` in [drivers/usb/class/cdc-acm.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.10/drivers/usb/class/cdc-acm.c#L1687)

**Careful** playing around with device drivers, even being `ttyACM` a terminal interface only if the interface tty->hardware is implemented poorly some command may break the hardware.

Perhaps this question should be in [Unix & Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The two barcode scanners in question apparently identify as the same PID and VID according to the manufacturer but have a different serial number. They said the newer scanner has a different MCU that controls the USB interface. So it looks as though the serial number is also used when determining the device class.

Comment: @LukeAllison, see [drivers/usb/core/driver.c:](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.10/drivers/usb/core/driver.c#L615), there are flags to match other criteria, if you look at the end of `acm_ids[]` the macro `USB_INTERFACE_INFO` match by *class* *subclass* and *proto*